# Access HashSet in jApplet from class

Tags: java, applet, hashset

I want to disaplay my Hashet in a jApplet.

The class Owner:

```
public class Owner implements Persistence {
private String SVNr = null;
private String Name = null;
public HashSet AllOwners = new HashSet();
```

After a new owner was created it will pushed into my HashSet. 
In the Applet I need to access this HashSet. I've tried something but it did not work.

```
private void fillListOwner() {
    HashSet OwnerList = new HashSet();
    OwnerList = Owner.AllOwner;
```

The HashSet from the class Owner (where all Owners are saved) should be accessible in the method fillListOwner in my Applet. 
How is it possible to get my owners in the HashSet OwnerList in the Applet? 
Further I would need to display the HashSet with the Owners in my jList element.

I have imported my class Owner.

Here is a screenshot from the jList where the Owners should be displayed:
[image: How can i fill the jList with my Owner Hashset from the class Owner]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As currently written, its hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @DavidPostill: I've edited my post and attached a picture, hopefully it is better to understand

Comment: Where is your code? Post your code in the question, see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: All the necessary code is already in my post @DavidPostill

Comment: No it isn't - **Complete – Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem** means something that can be compiled and run.